# How to Fade-in Captions in Backstretch

Tags: javascript

The following script (with the help of Stackoverflow members) now works perfectly to display random images with captions. However, In addition to the images fading in, how do you fade-in the captions as well?

```
// Preload
$(images).each(function(){
$("<img/>")[0].src = this.url;});

var images = new Array(); //array of imgs objects

images[0] = {url: "/images/backgrounds/l&h.jpg", caption: "Stan Laurel and Oliver Hardy"};
images[1] = {url: "/images/backgrounds/sherlock-watson.jpg", caption: "Basil Rathbone and Nigel Bruce"};
images[2] = {url: "/images/backgrounds/powell-loy.jpg", caption: "William Powell and Myrna Loy"};
images[3] = {url: "/images/backgrounds/conried-bergman-bogart.jpg", caption: "Paul Heinreid, Ingrid Bergman and Humphrey Bogart"};

function loadRandomImage(imgs) {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgs.length);

    console.log("loadRandomImages(): index = "+ index);

    $.backstretch(imgs[index].url, {fade: 1500, speed: 5000}); 

    $("#caption").html(imgs[index].caption);
}


// we run the function once at the beginning.
loadRandomImage(images);

// Change images every 5 seconds
setInterval(loadRandomImage, 5000, images);
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-backstretch/2.0.4/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
<div id="caption"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could just add a css transitiont ex: `#caption { transition: opacity 3s linear 0s }` to the css or add it in with vanilla js:

```
document.getElementById('caption').style.transition = 'opacity 3s linear 0s'
```

i dont know jQuery well but i'm sure theres a way

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but unfortunately, neither one works. The CSS method, which I had tried, is as if it's not even there.